# Syntax of method inside fragment

Tags: java, android, methods, fragment

could you please help with suggestion?
I'm trying to create method inside fragment, but facing with I believe some syntax error.

My code

```js
public class PageFragment1 extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {


public int addTwoInt(int a, int b)
{
    sum = a + b;
}

public void main (String[] args)
{
    int s = addTwoInt(1, 2);
    System.out.println("Sum of two integer values :"+ s);   
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

}
```

But when I copy it inside OnCreate activity, parameter "args" becoming red

```js
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater
                .inflate(R.layout.page_1, container
                
                public int addTwoInt(int a, int b)
        {
            sum = a + b;
            return sum;
        }

        public void main (String[] args)
        {
            int s = addTwoInt(1, 2);
            System.out.println("Sum of two integer values :"+ s);
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
}
```

Android Studio offers to create the variable "args", but I expect that there is something simple - something wrong with the syntax or something in code that needs to be slightly adjusted.
Actual method that I'm trying to create is more complicated with many variables that I create inside fragment, but to easiness of the code in my question I put that one basic element. But the structure of the method remains the same.
Appreciate your help community.

Comment: You can't stick methods in methods. It's as simple as that. You can stick types in methods and then stick methods in types, but you can't invoke a `main` in a method-local type, and from these snippets it does not sound like you'd want to do that here. Just `main` back out, or explain what you wanted to accomplish by moving it within.

Comment: thanks for answer. I'm trying create method inside fragment with spinners and check boxes. Depending on values in spinners and checkboxes it will give back different values. I'm using simple example of method to avoid complications. However I don't understand how to make correct syntax.